# Probability of a random variable being greater than the maximum among others plus a constant

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, density-function

Suppose we have $N+1$ i.i.d. random variables from a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^{2}$. That is:

$$X_{i}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2}),\quad i=1,\dots , N+1$$

Suppose $b>0$ is some known, positive number. We want to find the following probability:
$$Pr\left(X_{N+1}+b \geq \max\left(X_{1},X_{2},\dots , X_{N}\right)\right)$$.

Notice that we do not know the realizations, so we basically need to find:
$$Pr\left(\max\left(X_{1},X_{2},\dots , X_{N}\right)-X_{N+1}\leq b\right)$$.

How can we compute that? Would it be correct to derive the distribution of $\max\left(X_{1},X_{2},\dots , X_{N}\right)-X_{N+1}$, given the distribution of the maximum of $N$ normal random variables and given the distribution of $X_{N+1}$. Is this the only approach?

Comment: It is possible that you forgot to mention *independence* of the random variables.

Comment: Thanks! I now specify that the random variables are i.i.d.

Comment: Start by writing the cumulative distribution function of $\max\{X_1, \dots, X_N\}$.

Comment: I can write the cdf of $\max\{X_{1}, \dots X_{N}\}$ as $\Phi\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right)^{N}$. But how would you suggest going from there?

Comment: @iqz With $Y := \max\{X_1, \dots, X_N\}$, you've figured out $F_Y(y) := \operatorname{prob}(Y \leq y)$. What you're looking for is $\operatorname{prob}(Y \leq b + X_{N+1})$. You know the distribution of (the independent) $b + X_{N+1}$.